# Delayed start of mysql on Lamp server

Tags: virtualbox, mysql, lamp

Apologies if I'm covering something that has already been asked, but I've searched and found nothing that quite covers what I'm trying to do/fix.

I'm trying to configure a LAMP server on VirtualBox for use within a school environment. The idea being that students can create an manipulate databases ect and then access this using windows clients to call upon the data for various projects.

The bulk of the configuration was done weeks ago, but I recently noticed an intermittent issue where sometimes during startup, Mysql would attempt to start before the shared drives are fully mounted. Often this works fine because it seems like the order that everything starts changes slightly, so sometimes the drives mount before mysql tries to start and other times mysql starts first.

Because the server is designed to use within a school environment, I cant just give people access to log in and manually start the service and need to ensure that Mysql starts successfully every time.

I tried editing /etc/init/mysql.conf and modifying the "start on" parameter - but its either not using this at all, or none of the conditions I used are valid or relevant.

Can I delay the startup of Mysql until after either the drives have mounted, or even until a user logs into the server? (then I can create a generic account with no ability to break the server - and have them log in to ensure its running)

(I'm no expert on Linux and have been figuring this out on the fly because I basically inherited the project)
We're using Ubuntu 17.04 for reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Question: whet is the relation between MySQL and the mountpoints you use?  Because there should be no relation: the SQL database resides in `/var/` by default and nothing related to MySQL should be on a share (except maybe a backup or dump). Oh and maybe a simple thingy to alter in that config: `--service-startup-timeout=900` will delay mysql for 900 ms . 900 ms is the default so increase  it a bit and that might be enough to have the system mount the disks. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-server.html

Comment: Also: have a look in /var/log/ for any error messages; maybe it is something else than the mounting of the shares.

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the response. I should have specified that the databases were moved to the mountpoints deliberately and mysql pointed to look for them there.  The idea being that each student has a copy of the databases in their home directory and as they build new ones or new content it follows them from machine to machine. They can then log into any pc with the lamp setup installed on it and access their databases to work on their project.

Comment: Also, journalctl is whats pointing me to this being the fault. Im not at work so dont have access to paste a log of this but its showing that during startup of the lamp server,  if the shared drives mount before mysql starts it works fine,  otherwise it fails to start about 5 times and then errors out completely. I can log in with sudo privileges and start the service with no issue. When I'm at work I'll get a dump of the journalctl and paste it here.

Comment: "that the databases were moved to the mountpoints " Not a good idea ;-) I would use the normal /lib/, create databases on there and have them use workbench.

Comment: They're set like that due to various constraints. Basically each instance of the lamp server is part of a local virtual "network" on each host machine. The shared drives and the data being within them the way it is is essential to allow students to move from machine to machine and still work on their projects. 
Again, everything works fine if the drives just mount in the right order. I'm just looking for a fail-safe to ensure that MySql doesnt start (or at least timeout) before that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the previous question about your mount points.

Something's seems broken in your config.

Your MariaDB/MySQL data files should live in /var/lib/mysql which should be local to your container, so should always be available.

Take a look in /etc/fstab + ensure there's no mention of /var/lib/* + if there is you might prefer to scrape you containers + start again.

Then you'd create a **GRANT** allowing Windows clients access to your Virtualbox MariaDB/MySQL instances.

So there should be no... mucking about (tech term) with any local filesystems.